# Vba to Compare two columns in excel and fetch the corresponding values

Tags: excel, vba

I have two datas: Company Data and EPC Data respectively.
[image]

Here I need to compare Column A with Column E and put the corresponding of column B values(If matched) in column G.
Can this be done using VBA?

Any Help is Appreciated!

Comment: You can do this using `VLOOKUP()` - no VBA required.

Comment: Here the number of rows might be Dynamic (But same count in Col A and Col E) Will VLOOKUP() work in the above case?

Comment: Yes - why not try it out?

Comment: Yes its working!
Thanks a lot Tim, Good day ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0))
```

Put this in G2 and drag down as necesarry